# EncryptByPassPhrase key given in bytes

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, des, encryption-symmetric

Friends,

I want to use `EncryptByPassPhrase` in SQL SERVER (which I found here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190357.aspx) to update existing values in a table by encrypting them. However, the passphrase (or key) is given in bytes such as:

```
private static readonly byte[] TrippleDesKey = new byte[] { 0xF1, 0x07, 0xE6, 0x13, 0xBA, 0x85, 0x7F, 0xDC, 0x6D, 0x85, 0x67, 0x9B, 0x68, 0x7A, 0xC7, 0x1F, 0x10, 0xBA, 0xB0, 0x2F, 0xA2, 0xAE, 0xDA, 0xEA };
```

I want to apply `EncryptByPassPhrase` using the `TrippleDesKey` variable.

Any suggestions on how I can do that? I assume if I convert the `TrippleDesKey` variable into string I could just simple use it `EncryptByPassPhrase`.

I tried converting the `TrippleDesKey` variable such as

```
string result = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(TrippleDesKey); 
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

and the ouptut was ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½mï¿½gï¿½hzï¿½ï¿½ï¿½/ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½

I used ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½mï¿½gï¿½hzï¿½ï¿½ï¿½/ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ in EncryptByPassPhrase but no value is encrypted i.e., an empty string is returned.

Comment: how are you calling the SQL function? note it also accepts binary/varbinary passphrases so it might work if you just sent the byte array as parameter, ADO.NET will work to convert it to the SQL binary data type...

Comment: I was not planing on calling it from the C# code. I though I could just to something like EncryptByPassPhrase(' ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½mï¿½gï¿½hzï¿½ï¿½ï¿½/ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½', valueA)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just join the bytes hex values in only one value and use it:

```
new byte[] { 0xF1, 0x07, 0xE6, 0x13, 0xBA, 0x85, 0x7F, 0xDC, 0x6D, 0x85, 0x67, 0x9B, 0x68, 0x7A, 0xC7, 0x1F, 0x10, 0xBA, 0xB0, 0x2F, 0xA2, 0xAE, 0xDA, 0xEA } = 0xF107E613BA857FDC6D85679B687AC71F10BAB02FA2AEDAEA
```

Then use it like this:

```
EncryptByPassPhrase( 0xF107E613BA857FDC6D85679B687AC71F10BAB02FA2AEDAEA, 'test')
```

Answer (score 0):

EncryptByPassPhrase can accept a binary (byte) value as the passphrase, so you should be able to pass the TrippleDesKey as a parameter to a stored procedure or statement. I threw this together as an example, but it should be close...

```
string commandText = "UPDATE MyTable SET EncryptedData = EncryptByPassPhrase(@DesKey, EncryptedData ) WHERE CustomerID = @ID";

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandText, connection);
    command.Parameters.Add("@DesKey", SqlDbType.VarBinary);
    command.Parameters["@DesKey"].Value = TrippleDesKey;

    command.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int);
    command.Parameters["@ID"].Value = customerID;

    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        Int32 rowsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Console.WriteLine("RowsAffected: {0}", rowsAffected);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```